# Modal images with Javascript/Css3 practice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modal-dialog

i'm new here. I have a problem with the close button of my Modal images ( the class of my button images is

> div class = ".exit "

seems don't work... 
Probably cause i did some mistake with css  ,but i'm trying to learn step by step for everything case and i'm behind this issue since this morning.

I didn't find a good solution at moment....

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('mymodal');
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("exit")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";

}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
  body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  /*Disponi elementi in colonna*/
  flex-direction: column;
  /*Disponi al centro il testo*/
  justify-content: center;
  /*Disponi elementi al centro*/
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.container>h1 {
  font-family: 'Knewave', cursive;
  font-size: 3.5em;
}

.container>p {
  padding-left: 10em;
  padding-right: 10em;
  font-family: 'Knewave', cursive;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.gallery #myImg {
  /*SISTEMA L'HOVER RESPONSIVE DELLE IMMAGINI */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#myImg {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


/* APPLY OVERLAY TO DIV */

#myImg .over {
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .7;
}

#myImg:hover .over {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  opacity: .5;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fefefe;
}


/* Caption of Modal Image */

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}


/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.exit:hover,
.exit:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100`enter code here`%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--CONTAINER PRINCIPALE-->
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Test </h1>
    <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer fermentum posuere tristique. Pellentesque at egestas arcu, in sollicitu </p>
    <div class="gallery">
      <div class="img-container" id="myImg">
        <!--IMAGE MODAL-->
        <img id="pic1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt="prova">

        <!--MODAL-->

        <div id="mymodal" class="modal">

          <div class="modal-content">
            <!--BUTTON EXIT-->
            <span class="exit">&times;</span>
            <!--IMAGE INSIDE MODAL-->
            <img id="img01">
            <!--CAPTION-->
            <div id="caption">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--END MODAL-CONTENT-->

        </div>
        <!--END MODAL-->

        <!--OVERLAY-->
        <div class="over"></div>


      </div>
      <!--END IMG-CONTAINER  -->


    </div>
    <!----END GALLERY-->

  </div>
  <!--END  -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain whats the problem

Comment: The close button of the modal image dosen't work.  If you click on my image ..it show the modal,but if you want close it for back on the page... the button "X" dosen't  work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I noticed your problem is that you cant close your modal after you open it.

To solve this we need to take a look at your listeners:

You have two listeners
`#myImg` click open modal
`.exit` click close modal

The problem is in your `HTML`
`.exit` is a child of `#myImg`, this means every time you click on `.exit` you also call the `#myImg` listener. To solve this we can take the `div` that contains your modal outside of the `div` with `myImg` as id.

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('mymodal');
var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("exit")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
img.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  /*Disponi elementi in colonna*/
  flex-direction: column;
  /*Disponi al centro il testo*/
  justify-content: center;
  /*Disponi elementi al centro*/
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.container>h1 {
  font-family: 'Knewave', cursive;
  font-size: 3.5em;
}

.container>p {
  padding-left: 10em;
  padding-right: 10em;
  font-family: 'Knewave', cursive;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.gallery #myImg {
  /*SISTEMA L'HOVER RESPONSIVE DELLE IMMAGINI */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#myImg {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}


/* APPLY OVERLAY TO DIV */

#myImg .over {
  padding: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: .7;
}

#myImg:hover .over {
  display: block;
  background: red;
  opacity: .5;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;
  /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content (image) */

.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fefefe;
}


/* Caption of Modal Image */

#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}


/* Add Animation */

.modal-content,
#caption {
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1)
  }
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {
    transform: scale(0)
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1)
  }
}


/* The Close Button */

.exit {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.exit:hover,
.exit:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .modal-content {
    width: 100`enter code here`%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!--CONTAINER PRINCIPALE-->
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Test </h1>
    <p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer fermentum posuere tristique. Pellentesque at egestas arcu, in sollicitu </p>
    <div class="gallery">
      <div class="img-container" id="myImg">
        <!--IMAGE MODAL-->
        <img id="pic1" src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x400" alt="prova">

        

        <!--OVERLAY-->
        <div class="over"></div>


      </div>
      <!--END IMG-CONTAINER  -->


    </div>
    <!----END GALLERY-->

  </div>
  <!--END  -->
<!--MODAL-->

        <div id="mymodal" class="modal">

          <div class="modal-content">
            <!--BUTTON EXIT-->
            <span class="exit">&times;</span>
            <!--IMAGE INSIDE MODAL-->
            <img id="img01">
            <!--CAPTION-->
            <div id="caption">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!--END MODAL-CONTENT-->

        </div>
        <!--END MODAL-->
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you!!  :D  i need practice